# Does scrubbing a ssd drive work to completely remove deleted files in situations where the trim command is not supported?

Tags: linux, ssd, arch-linux, trim, manjaro

There are situations where it's not possible to run the trim command, for example some external usb ssd drives don't support it.

If you're not concerned with the ssd drive degrading in any way, shape or form, does scrubbing work to completely remove deleted files in the free space of ssd drives?

Is this also a solution to wipe deleted files on a non trim supported ssd drive, even if it might be less effective?

Comment: Scrubbing using the secure delete or some other method?

Comment: Used the [scrub](https://github.com/chaos/scrub) tool on github, tried scrubbing with random data and zeros.

Comment: That tool is not sufficient to securely erase a SSD.  You should use the secure erase method, if your SSD has one, otherwise you risk your data still existing on the drive in some capacity.

Comment: I'm looking for a method to securely erase contents inside the free space of an encrypted ssd drive without using trim. I don't want to erase my linux installation because I just want some files to permanently be deleted.

Comment: Well even TRIM doesn't do that but if the data is encrypted then it doesn't matter, any recoverable data, would be random data.

Comment: Not if my encryption key is compromised. Trim also doesn't completely securely erase free space on a drive? Thought it permanently deleted files. Also came to this conclusion after my own tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more intensive scrubbing with the command line scrub tool (scrub -X -p schneier test which does 7 passes) I could recover only 1/10th of what I could recover before. So I guess it does have effect.

Answer (score 1):

One pass erase is enough. Any additional passes cause unnecessary wearing of your disk. SSDs can't hold old data after overwriting in any way. However you need to write all free space to be sure. You can use commands like:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/home/clean.big
rm /home/clean.big
```

In Windows you can use [SDelete](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/sdelete.aspx).